# Splitting the data by day and creating a line graph to show over time within the day while layering each id over each other

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-analysis

I have a dataset called `hourly_steps_merged` with many unique IDs in the `Id` column. I want to group the data by `Date` and `Id` since I have a month's worth of data. I want to layer the unique IDs over each other to compare them and analyze the dataset better. I want to be able to do this in Seaborn.

list of columns: ["Id", "ActivityHour", "StepTotal"]

```
hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'] = pd.to_datetime(hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'])
hourly_steps_merged['Date'] = hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'].dt.date
hourly_steps_merged['Time'] = hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'].dt.time
hourly_steps_merged['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(hourly_steps_merged['Time'].astype(str))
```

The new list of columns: ["Id", "ActivityHour", "StepTotal", "Date", "Time"]

Number of Rows: 22099

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood you request, you can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'] = pd.to_datetime(
    hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'])
hourly_steps_merged['Date'] = hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'].dt.date
hourly_steps_merged['Time'] = hourly_steps_merged['ActivityHour'].dt.hour
df = hourly_steps_merged.groupby(['Date', 'Id', 'Time'])[
    'StepTotal'].sum().reset_index()
for i in df['Date'].unique():
    data = df[df['Date'] == i]
    name = str(i)
    plt.figure(name)
    sns.barplot(data=data, x="Time", y="StepTotal", hue="Id").set(title=name)
```

Comment: It worked well, but it was just not exactly what I wanted. It has all the days in a single figure. I was looking more for each day being in it's own sub-figure and having a different chart per day with all the unique IDs. so I can look at each day individually and compare the hourly step count of each ID.

Comment: I was update my answer and hope it would be better for you